# 'raco' is not recognized on the windows 10 command line

Tags: plugins, racket, raco

I'm trying to get familiar with DrRacket plugin framework, and I'm using the following tutorial:

https://lang.video/blog/2018/03/21/making-an-ide-plugin-for-drracket/

I'm stuck at the step where raco is used:

[image]

When i run the command, my windows 10 operating system gives back the following error message, How can i solve this?:

'raco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

second question:

I've also tried putting the clippy folder into a folder within my program files, in the DrRacket installation. Is this the location where Racket Plugins should reside, or can they be placed in any folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `racket` and `raco` to your Windows PATH (the directories in which Windows looks for commands).

https://beautifulracket.com/setting-the-windows-path.html